# Wordpress : How can add span to menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i have menuin wordpress like this :-

```
<div id="my_custom_class">
 <ul class="my_custom_class">
   <li class="page_item"><a href="#">page_item</a>
 <ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item child"><a href="#">children</a></li>
 </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
   <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
   <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

this menu will be create wheni use this :-

```
<? wp_nav_menu('menu=header'); ?>
```

so i need when any `li` have child, add `<span></span>` tag befor  tag like this

```
   <div id="my_custom_class">
     <ul class="my_custom_class">
       <li class="page_item"><span></span><a href="#">page_item</a>
     <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li class="page_item child"><a href="#">children</a></li>
     </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
       <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
       <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
     </ul>

</div>
```

how can i do that. by jquery

Comment: Are you referring to the top level list items only?

Comment: You can try to do this serverside by messing about with the `wp_nav_menu_objects` hook

Comment: I will recommend you consider a server side solution as @Joren recommends.  With WordPress, tinkering with ad-hoc jQuery can cause unintended results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('ul.my_custom_class li a').closest('li').prepend('<span></span>');
```

[***Live DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfh8Y/)

[***Live DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfh8Y/5)

```
$('ul.my_custom_class li:has(ul)').prepend('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

By jQuery? Ok:

```
$('<span></span>').prependTo('ul.my_custom_class li:has(ul)');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't willing to dig in to wordpress' functionality, you can inject the `<span>` elements with regex:

`(<li.*class="[^\"]*page_item[^\"]*"[^>]*>)(<a.*</a>[^<]+<ul)`

Result:

```
<div id="my_custom_class">
<ul class="my_custom_class">
<li class="page_item"><span></span><a href="#">page_item</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item child"><a href="#">children</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">current_page</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

`$1` = `<li class="page_item">`

`$2` = `<a href="#">page_item</a><ul`

And so you just `preg_replace` with `\1<span></span>\2` (you will need to add a backslash to the `</a>`)

[Example on php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pei-xsq) (assuming I generated the link correctly lol)